# Are Tether(USDT) and Ethereum the same? Do we need different wallet for different one?

Tags: erc-20, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

So far, we have ERC-20 (Ethereum), TRC-20 (TRON blockchain) and BEP-20 (Binance Smart Chain), Which one would you recommend?

If we just use one wallet (ideally FOSS one) which one would you recommend?

Would like have a wallet to store some tokens when my customers pay me. But we have many tokens, not sure which one to be my payments.

Can we use the same wallet to store different tokens which are created by different blockchain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question, ERC20 compliant tokens respect the same ideas, doesn't matter what blockchain they are on. Erc20, TRC20 or BEP20 are all the same standard token, with the same standard functions, but on different blockchains.

For the title of your question, Tether is not the same as Ethereum.
Tether is an ERC20 compliant token on the ethereum blockchain.
Ether, the native currency of Ethereum blockchain, is NOT erc20 compliant. That's why WETH (wrapped ether) was created.

I'm not sure I understood your question so please follow up with me here if you need.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes. Can we use the same wallet to store different tokens which are created by different blockchain? Does ERC20 compliant token have any benefits

Comment: Yes you can use the same wallet. If you look at metamask, with the same address you can switch between different blockchain and interact with different tokens. Not sure about Tron's blockchain, but from metamask you can switch from ethereum mainnet to ethereum testnets, avax, binance smart chain, .... ERC20 compliant tokens have a lot of benefits and the erc20 standard helped a lot to further DeFi by given the industry a standard of tokens that have known functions. Every erc20 tokens react to functions like transfer(), transferFrom(), approve(), ... It help integration of new tokens

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the same wallet to store different tokens which are created by different blockchains. ERC20 compliant tokens have benefits because they follow a specific approach for creating fungible tokens, ensuring that they all share similar properties without creating special logic for each new token.

See: https://www.alchemy.com/overviews/erc20-solidity